# Need help making changes to my RollUp Summary Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, class

I have created a Rollup Summary Trigger that will display a count of Assignments__c on the parent Contact page layout. The process for this has changed and now I need this field to display a sum of the Level__c field on the Assignment object. The Level field can only be populated with the following values: 1, 2, 3, or 4.

> So if there are 3 Assignments associated to the Contact and they all have the Level field populated with the number 2. Then on the Contact the Total_Levels__c field should read 6.

Below is the current Apex Class followed by the Apex Trigger that I am using.

```
public with sharing class AssignmentServices {
public static void updateContacts(List<pse__Assignment__c> assignments)
{
    Set<Id> contactIds = new Set<Id>();
    for (pse__Assignment__c assignment : assignments) contactIds.add(assignment.pse__Resource__c);
    setTotalLevels(contactIds);
}
public static void setTotalLevels(Set<Id> contactIds)
{
    List<Contact> records = new List<Contact>();
    for (AggregateResult aggregate : [
        SELECT pse__Resource__c, count(Id) records
        FROM pse__Assignment__c
        WHERE Active_Assignment__c = true
        GROUP BY pse__Resource__c
    ]) records.add(generateRecord(aggregate));
    update records; // proper error handling advised
}
static Contact generateRecord(AggregateResult aggregate)
{
    return new Contact(
        Id=(Id)aggregate.get('pse__Resource__c'),
        Total_Levels__c=(Integer)aggregate.get('records')
    );
}}
```

The trigger:

```
trigger pseAssignment on pse__Assignment__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {
if (trigger.isAfter)
{
    if (trigger.isInsert)
    {
        AssignmentServices.updateContacts(trigger.new);
    }
    if (trigger.isUpdate)
    {
        AssignmentServices.updateContacts(trigger.new);
    }
    if (trigger.isDelete)
    {
        AssignmentServices.updateContacts(trigger.old);
    }
}}
```

Comment: What is your specific problem?

Comment: Where exactly are you having trouble with updating your code? What have you tried to do to update it that hasn't worked? As written, it sounds as though you're asking us to write your code for you..

Comment: Oh my apologies. I am unfamiliar with this method and using the aggregate results function. I am curious as to whether or not I need to change that to a sum function or what is the best way to start looking into making this change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Level__c` is a numeric field, this change:

```
SELECT pse__Resource__c, sum(Level__c) records
```

should do it.

See the [Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_agg_functions.htm) documentation.

Comment: I already tried this and upon testing I received the following error: Invalid conversion from runtime type Decimal to Integer: Class.AssignmentServices.generateRecord: line 23, column 1

Comment: I fixed this issue. I didn't even notice that I was declaring that as an Integer instead of a Decimal like I should have been.